# How can I import a django model from one project into another project, both the projects use same database

Tags: python, django

File structure -

root/

```
project1/
        app1/models.py
        project1/

project2/
        app2/views.py
        project2/
```

Now I want to import a model from project1/app1/models.py into project2/app2/views.py .

How can I achieve this?

I had a larger django project earlier but I have to split the project into different micro-services due to dependency issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be use import in your views.py. here is an example how you can import project1 in your project2 views.

**model.py**

```
class project1(models.Model)
     ......

class project2(models.Model)
      .....
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import project1

def Project2view(request):
    project1 = project1.objects.all()
```

Comment: is there a method without defining the models again?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do that, you don't want to have direct dependencies between different Django projects, it would be a mess to maintain.
I suggest to try to figure out a different solution such as providing APIs to communicate between projects or using an AMQP broker.